# Stdin and stdout don't appear to be redirected to pipe

Tags: python, c++, pipe, fork

I have to run a bunch of programs in parallel, via fork(), dup2, and pipes;  
(programs: rgen, A1, A2 and the driver program itself A3).
- A3 starts and executes rgen (via fork) with cml arguments; 
- rgen passes stdout to A1 (via pipe 'toA1'); 
- A1 needs to take stdin from rgen (via pipe 'toA1'), process that and then send stdout to A2 (via pipe 'toA2'); 
- A2 needs to take stdin from A1 (from pipe 'toA2'); 
- A2 then takes that input and sends what it got from A1 to stdout (screen), it then waits for user input from A3 (via pipe 'toA2') or for input from A1 via pipe 'toA2';
- Then the driver program needs to get stdin from the keyboard and send stdout to A2 (via pipe 'toA2');

The issue is that pipe 'toA2' doesn't appear to be working. I know that A1 sends the correct output to stdout. And I know that A2 receives input from stdin. Currently A2 receives stdin from the keyboard as noted from "std::cin >> use_input" and the fact that when I run the program it doesn't do anything else unless I input something into the command line.

It should look like this in the terminal:

```
$./A3 -s 5 -n 4 -l 5
V 8
E {<0,2>,<0,3>,<0,4>,<1,3>,<4,7>,<5,2>,<5,6>}
s 2 4
2-0-4
```

where "./A3 -s 5 -n 4 -l 5" and "s 2 4" are user inputs into the command line and "V 8" and "E {...}" and "2-0-4" are all output to the screen by A2.

*fyi all of the individual programs work just fine (maybe not A3 since it's the only with the potential issue), I'm more worried about getting the information from other processes.

I've removed all of the code in my programs that are not to do with stdin or stdout and replaced it with "...". If it is necessary to show, let me know, I just thought it'd be easier to read this way since I know it works once I have then input.

Program A3 (c++):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

std::string user_input;
std::vector<pid_t> kids;
pid_t child_pid;
char* empty_arg1[2];
empty_arg1[0] = "A1.py";
empty_arg1[1] = nullptr;
char* empty_arg2[2];
empty_arg2[0] = "A2";
empty_arg2[1] = nullptr;

int toA1[2];
int toA2[1];
pipe(toA1);
pipe(toA2);

child_pid = fork();
//runs rgen; Sends output to 'toA1'
if (child_pid == 0) {

    dup2(toA1[1], STDOUT_FILENO); //Sends stdout to pipe 'toA1'
    close(toA1[0]);
    close(toA1[1]);

    return execv("./rgen", argv);
}

kids.push_back(child_pid);

child_pid = fork();
//runs A1; Sends output to 'toA2'; Gets input from pipe 'toA1'
if (child_pid == 0) {

    dup2(toA1[0], STDIN_FILENO);    //A1 gets stdin from pipe 'toA1'
    close(toA1[0]);
    close(toA1[1]);

    dup2(toA2[1], STDOUT_FILENO); //sends stdout to pipe 'toA2'
    close(toA2[0]);
    close(toA2[1]);

    return execvp("./A1.py", empty_arg1);
}

kids.push_back(child_pid);

child_pid = fork();
//runs A2; Gets input from 'toA2'
if (child_pid == 0) {

    std::string use_input = "blank";
    dup2(toA2[0], STDIN_FILENO); //A2 gets stdin from pipe 'toA2'
    close(toA2[0]);
    close(toA2[1]);
    std::cout << "use_input[1] = " << use_input << std::endl;
    return execv("./A2", empty_arg2);
}

kids.push_back(child_pid);

dup2(toA2[1], STDOUT_FILENO); //Sends output to 'toA2'
close(toA2[0]);
close(toA2[1]);

while (!std::cin.eof()) {

    getline(std::cin, user_input); //Assumes there will be a space after the command
    std::cout << user_input << std::endl;

}

// sends kill signal to all children processes
for (int i = 0; i < kids.size(); i++) {
    int status;
    kill(kids[i], SIGTERM);
    waitpid(kids[i], &status, 0);
}

return 0;
}
```

Program rgen (c++):

```
...

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

........

    // removes pre-existing streets
            std::cout << output << std::endl;
            street_names.pop_back();
        }
    }

........

    //Outputs the 'a' command to add the streets for assignment 1

    std::cout << output << std::endl;
    std::cout << "g" << std::endl;
    sleep(wait_sec);
}

return 0;
}
```

Program A1 (python):

```
...

def main():

sys.stdout.write("From A1 forked process\n")

.....

        sys.stdout.write("V " + str(len(vertex_list)) + "\n")
        sys.stdout.write(str_edges + "\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Program A2 (c++):

```
int main() {

std::string use_input = "NOPE";
std::cerr << "A2 is running" << std::endl;
std::cin >> use_input;
std::cout << "use_input[2] = " << use_input << std::endl;

while (!std::cin.eof()) {

    getline(std::cin, user_input); //Assumes there will be a space after the command

    std::istringstream iss(user_input);
    iss >> command;
    if (command == 'V') {

       ....

    }
    else if (command == 'E') {

        ...         

        iss >> edges;
        std::cout << "V " << num_vert << std::endl;
        std::cout << "E " << edges << std::endl;

        ...

    }
    else if (command == 's') {

        ...

        iss >> str_vert >> end_vert;

         ....

            std::cout << path;
            std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Error: Invalid command[a2]" << std::endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume it's some super simple fix that I'm not seeing, since yesterday I had a brain fart and made an array of 2 things with int array[1] instead of int array[2]

Comment: could you perform some information reduction so that we don't need to dive in 300 lines of code, please

Comment: ya sorry, hopefully it is more readable now